# Gmail API reply to a thread with a new subject

Tags: python, gmail-api

In gmail, when you click "Reply", you have the option to "Edit subject" if you want to reply and quote an existing thread in a new thread with a different subject.

I have managed to send an email either in a new thread, or reply to an existing thread, but have not figured out how to achieve the behaviour I explained above.

I believe I'm looking for a "quote thread" functionality, but am not too sure how to properly achieve this.

Below is a small code snippet for some context:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['To'] = "email.com"
msg['From'] = "email.com
msg['Subject'] = "Subject"
msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))
body = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(msg.as_string()), 'threadId': thread_id} 
service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=body).execute()
```

EDIT: What I'm trying to achieve:

### Email 1; Thread 1:

Subject: Subject1

Hey Dude
How's everything

### Email 2; Thread 1:

Subject: Subject1

Yo Dude,
Y u no reply?

On Tue, Nov 3, 2015 at 10:41 AM, Dude 
| Hey Dude
| How's everything

### Email 3; Thread 2:

Subject: Subject2

Dude,
Will a different subject make you reply?

On Tue, Nov 3, 2015 at 10:42 AM, Dude 
| Yo Dude,
| Y u no reply?
|
| On Tue, Nov 3, 2015 at 10:41 AM, Dude 
| | Hey Dude
| | How's everything

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. After reading your question a couple of times it sounds like you have two threads (A, B) and you want to reply to thread B with the contents of an email from thread A quoted?

Comment: I edited my question with an example.

Comment: Changing the subject of the reply isn't accomplishing what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the subject of a reply will always create a new thread. It is not possible to change the subject of an existing thread.

Comment: I'm not trying to create a new thread. I just want to quote the old thread in a new thread that I'm creating. "if you want to reply and quote an existing thread in a new thread with a different subject"